# Automorphism group of $\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{F}_q)$

Tags: automorphism-group, general-linear-group, classical-groups

In the book [On the Automorphisms of the Classical Groups, J. Dieudonné](https://bookstore.ams.org/memo-1-2/)  the author describes all the automorphisms of $\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{F}_q)$, but I couldn't find a description of the automorphism group as a group, for example what is it isomorphic to or what is the cardinality of the group. Can someone throw some light on the mentioned questions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [In French document](http://vonbuhren.free.fr/Agregation/Documents/agreg_document_denombrement_espace%20vectoriel_fini.pdf) providing answers to your questions.

Comment: On MathOverFlow they believe that Dieudonne's book answers the question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/123551/the-automorphism-group-of-the-general-linear-group-gln-f

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I don't see where those notes address the isomorphism class of $\operatorname{Aut}(\operatorname{GL}(n,\Bbb F_q))$, or its cardinality. They just list a few somewhat elementary results of linear algebra over finite fields.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net the linked article talks about cardinality of $\text{GL}(n,q)$ and not the group of automorphisms of $\text{GL}(n,q)$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician chapter 4 of the book describes what will be the automorphisms of the group in case the field is of characteristic $2$, but not precisely the group in general.

Comment: @user300 Yes, I was only reporting a fact. But doesn't chapter II deal with the case of odd characteristic? I don't have Dieudonne's book to hand.

Comment: @ancientmathematician  Chapter II also does the same i.e. just says what are the automorphisms, but not what the automorphism group is.

Comment: Your question is a very good one: one seldom knows everything about the elements of a group and still finds it hard to describe the structure! But doesn't the description of the elements let us compute at least the order? Something like the order of $P\Gamma L$ times $\phi(q-1)$ times $2$?